# Making sure a bash script is run as script-specified user

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I want to make sure that the script doesn't get run as root on accident.

What could I put at the beginning of the script that checks if the script is being run by a specific user and if not echo a sentence then completely stop the script from finishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this line after `#!/bin/bash`:

```
[ "$USER" = root ] && echo "This script shouldn't be run as root. Aborting." && exit 1
```

This is roughly the equivalent of:

```bsh
if [ "$USER" = root ]; then
    echo "This script shouldn't be run as root. Aborting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Worked great after changing the wording. Didnt like that " 'You're "

Comment: @JackaryZ Fancier now? :)

Comment: Oh @kos I meant the console didnt like the apostrophe in you're haha I guess it thought something was being closed. So I just re worded it. Not that I personally had an issue with the wording haha.

Comment: @JackaryZ Indeed, sorry! that was just me being silly. I just noticed that :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, it just tells how to bail out if you're not the specified user.